# How to Compile Apache Spark with Scala 2.11.1 using SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

I've been trying to compile Apache spark with `scala-2.11.1` (the latest version at the time). However, each time I try it ends up compiling everything to `scala-2.10.*`. I don't understand why.

The official documentation suggests that we use maven for compilation after switching to 2.11 using script in the `dev/` folder.

What if I wanted to use sbt instead?

Comment: The current latest version of Scala is 2.11.6 by the way.

Comment: @DaleWijnand, thanks. By the way, am I correct in assuming that fetching dependencies for scala-2.11.* is same weather it is *.1 or *.6?

Comment: Yes. It wasn't true in the 2.9 days, but that doesn't matter much these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable `scala-2.11` profile

```
>sbt -Dscala-2.11=true
sbt> compile
```